# Algorithm (or regular expression) needed to find multiple instances of anything

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not sure if there is a simple way of doing this, but is there a way to find multiple instances in an unknown string?  For example:

```
hellohellohellobyebyebyehello
```

Without knowing the value of the above string, can I return something that will tell me that there are 3 instances of "hello" and 3 instances of "bye" (I'm not worried about the last hello however as I'm looking for consecutive repetition.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are they always dictionary words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"testhellohellohellobyebyebyehello".match(/(.+)\1+/)`

This says : "match a sequence of at least 1 character `(.+)`, then reference that first thing we found `\1` at least one time `+` or more.

It will return `["hellohellohello", "hello"]` meaning hellohellohello matches the full expression (expression 0), and "hello" matches expression 1 (the thing we reference with `\1`).

**Caveat:**
something like `"hahahaha"` will yield `["hahahaha", "haha"]`, instead of `["hahahaha", "ha"]`. so you'll need to use the above with some post-processing to get to your desired result.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the Sequitur algorithm can help: http://sequitur.info/

Answer (score 4):

```
s = "hellohellohellobyebyebyehello"
s.replace(/(.+)(\1+)/g, function($0, $1) {
    console.log($1 + " repeated " + ($0.length / $1.length) + " times");
});
```

Comment: +1 for being innovative. Make the first `+` nongreedy (`/(.+?)(\1+)/`) or it will match `hellohello` repeated 2 times instead of a `hello` repeated 4 times (if there are 4 (or more) hello's in the string)

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking up for dictionary words, you can load your lexicon in a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree), 
then consider the characters of your string one by one and go through your tree. Each time your reach a leaf you increment by one the associated "word".

Comment: A prefix tree is enough and it is very easy to implement even in javascript.

Comment: I removed what I said about javascript as I'm not an expert... and true, a prefix tree is enough, easier to implement but less optimized

Answer (score 0):

```
var source = "asdhellohellohellobyehellohellohellohelloasdhello";
var key = "hello";
var len = key.length;
var res = 0, tempres, next;
var last = source.indexOf(key);
while(last != -1)
{
  tempres = 0;
  next = last;
  while(true)
  {
    tempres++;
    next += len;
    last = source.indexOf(key, next);
    if(last != next)
      break;
  }
  res = (tempres > res) ? tempres : res;
}
console.log(res);//4
```